# print or display variable inside function

Tags: r, printing

Is there a way to `print` or display the value of a variable while inside a function, as opposed to printing the value outside the function after the function has been called?

I am virtually certain there is and thought the code was called `reveal` or something similar, but I cannot recall the correct term.

```
my.function <- function(x) {

  y <- x^2
 #  reveal(y)
 #  display(y)

 # desired result is to print or display here:
 # [1] 16

  cat(y)
  print(y)
  return(y)  
}

x <- 4

my.function(x)
#16[1] 16
#[1] 16
```

`cat(y)`, `print(y)` and `return(y)` all print outside the function.  Thank you for any advice.

**EDIT**

I found a similar question here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-November/027348.html

The response to that question from Peter Dalgaard was to uncheck an option called `buffered output` under the `Misc` tab.  However, that does not seem to be working in my case.  Perhaps the questions are unrelated.

Comment: I am confused. What do you mean, they print outside the function? What you are saying is impossible, because `4` has not even been passed to the function...

Comment: The number 16 appears after the `}`.

Comment: Of course it does! There is no way to pass `4` to the function before defining it.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing myself clearly.  I am not trying to print `4`.  I am trying to print `16`.

Comment: You cannot print `16` while defining the function in the console. What you are asking is impossible.

Comment: Can you explain your rationale behind this? Surely we're misinterpreting your wishes somehow...

Comment: I am trying to debug a function and thought it would be very helpful if I could see output inside the function as it progressed.

Comment: Take a look at `?debug`, which will step through the function and allow you to inspect objects at different points in the function's execution. To give it a go, try `debug(my.function); my.function(4)`, and then enter `y` at any point after its definition and before the call to `return`.

Comment: You can also try `message` which does a good job of "printing from within functions" -- I've used it for debugging with parallel operations, too.

Comment: @GaryWeissman Thank you!  Please consider posting a working example as an answer.  I tend to wait two days to accept an answer.  Your suggestion sounds very helpful and I could very well accept yours.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can put `print()` calls (or `cat()` calls for that matter) inside the function and if the execution reaches that point, then an output will be produced on the console even if an error later occurs later in execution. (It's possible that `flush.console()` will be needed if the IDE you are using is set for "buffered output".)

```
 > myf <- function(x){ print(x); y <- x^2; print(y); error() }
> myf(4)
[1] 4
[1] 16
Error in myf(4) : could not find function "error"
```

It's probably more elegant to use the browser() function as the debugging route. You set up its operation by changing options():

```
> options(error=recover)
> myf(4)
[1] 4
[1] 16
Error in myf(4) : could not find function "error"

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: myf(4)

Selection: 1
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> x
[1] 4
Browse[1]> y
[1] 16
Browse[1]>    # hit a <return> to exit the browser 

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: myf(4)

Selection: 0   # returns you to the console
```

Comment: Very nice.  Clear examples of the browser function and the debug function are valuable.  I would upvote twice if I could.

Answer (score 31):

I like to use the `message` function to print for debugging, since it seems to reach the console from whatever dark depths it might be emitting from. For example:

```
somefunc <- function(x) {
       message(paste('ok made it this far with x=',x))
       # some stuff to debug
       message(paste('ok made it this far with x^2=',x^2))
       # some more stuff to debug
       message(paste('ok made it to the end of the function with x^3=',x^3))
}
```

Comment: Nice function! I had a ``print()`` wrapped around a ``prettyNum()``  that was returning ``0.0001000000000001`` in the console. Changing ``print()`` to ``message()`` gave me the ``0.0001`` I wanted. ``print()`` seems to ignore ``prettyNum()`` in some cases, not sure what it's all about...

Answer (score 8):

When I asked this question I might have been thinking of the `show` function which allows you to see the values of a variable without including that variable in the `return` statement.  Although, the `show` command prints values outside of the function.

```
my.function <- function(x) {
     y <- x^2
     show(y)
     show(length(y))
     z <- y + x
     return(z)
}

x <- 1:10

my.function(x)

 # [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
 # [1] 10
 # [1]   2   6  12  20  30  42  56  72  90 110
```

**EDIT: March 19, 2021**

Another way to view results from inside a function is to send an object to a global variable.  This might be helpful in locating errors inside a function.

```
my.function <- function(x) {
     y <- x^2
     y <<- y
     z <- y + x
     z <<- z
     return(z)
}
y
#[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
z
#[1]   2   6  12  20  30  42  56  72  90 110
x <- 1:10
my.function(x)
#[1]   2   6  12  20  30  42  56  72  90 110
```

Comment: The `show` function is not necessarily going to return a value. It will display whatever is defined as the result of the `show` function for S4 objects. For S4 objects of a class without a specific `show` method defined, it calls `showDefault` and will output a message about its class and then iterate over the slots. For ordinary objects of a basic or S3 class, it just calls `print`. I suppose it is safer in the sense of not choking if the object is a list (as `cat` would).

Comment: I didn't think that `<<-` necessarily assigns in the global environment. Rather I believe it gets assigned in the calling environment, which might or might not be the global environment. However when I check that against the help page I find it "cause[s] a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment. "