# Print() function isn't printing variable within loop/function (R Code)

Tags: r, function, loops, printing

I'm running a while loop and I added a print(Variable) so that my code would display the variable while the function is running but it is not printing.
This is what my code looks like:

```
Variable = matrix[ncol=4, nrow=3]
Variable[,1] <- c(1,1,1,1)
Variable[,2] <- c(2,2,2,2)
Variable[,3] <- c(3,3,3,3)

x=1
while(x==1)
{x <- readline("Do any columns need to be combined? Yes=1 No=0  Ans= ")
 y <- headline("First column to combine:  " )
 z <- headline("Second column to combine:  ")
Variable[,y] <- Variable[,y] + Variable[,z]
Variable = as.data.table(Variable)
Variable = Variable[,as.numeric(z):=NULL]
print(Variable)
x <- headline("Do any more columns need to be combined? Yes=1 No=0 Ans= ")
}
```

I've tried **flush.console()** before and after the "print(Variable)" line.

I've tried **ctr + W** which is supposed to bring up the Misc menu (Is this base R only? I'm using R Studio. I'm assuming you're supposed to click on the console before ctrl + W but it's just closing my open scripts).

I've tried the **message()** function which prints the Variable as *c(1,1,1,1)c(2,2,2,2)c(3,3,3,3)*.

I've tried **cat()** which got me the error *(Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'))*

And I've tried the **return()** function which got me the error *Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level*.

Which I found from similar posts:

[print or display variable inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740082/print-or-display-variable-inside-function)

and

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-November/027348.html

but I have not found a solution to my issue. Anyone have any other ideas or might know why its not printing and what I can do about it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

print.data.frame(Variable) works. Of course I figured it out two seconds after I posted it...but hour and hours of messing with this.

Comment: Score one for [rubber-ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)!